# How to link django reporting tool to my Django template page

Tags: django, reporting

I am using **django-reporting 0.21** tool for report generating, it's generate the csv file and graph through the django admin page(like 127.0.0.1:8000/reporting).

Using this url every one use the reporting link, but i need it's secure few persons can be view this link only.

Comment: how you identify the people by logging only?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL by

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    [...]
    (r'^you_own_reporting_url/', include('reporting.urls')),
)
```

And in `django-reporting` there are only two URL's, you can call them anywhere in your template by

```
{% url reporting-list %}
{% url reporting-view variable_slug %}
```